# input data with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i try to learn angular.
i want to create an input, when we input data then the data will show up on same page.
my code like this

```
<body ng-controller="nameCtrl">
  <div class="body container">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}} <!-- place for all username -->
          <a href="" ng-click="removename(name)">remove</a> <!-- button remove -->
        </li>
    </ul>

    <form action="" ng-submit="addName()">
      <label for="">first name :</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="firstname"> 
      <label for="">last name :</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="lastname">
      <input type="submit" value="add"> <!-- button add -->
    </form>
  </div>
</body>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('nameCtrl',function($scope){
    // ARRAY
    $scope.names=['firstname1 lastname1','firstname2 lastname2','firstname3 lastname3'];
    // ADD NAME
    $scope.addName= function(){
    $scope.names.push($scope.firstname +' '+ $scope.lastname);
    $scope.firstname="";
    $scope.lastname="";
  };
    //REMOVENAME
    $scope.removename= function(name){
    var i= $scope.names.indexOf(name);
    $scope.names.splice(i,1);
    };
});
```

on local (my computer) its work, but when i try to test it with jsfiddle. it didnt work, doest this this mean the code can work at online?
here the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/hec57h2a/

Answer (score 0):

aw silly me i forgot to bring tag `html` on jsfiddle, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-app` in body , it will work

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="nameCtrl">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="nameCtrl"> replace first line
```

Answer (score 0):

Add AngularJS in your HTML file.

Comment: here is the link.
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>